# Weird behaviour on booting after uninstalling Mate and Budgie Desktop

Tags: boot, 20.04, gnome, mate, budgie

I have Ubuntu 20.04. I wanted to try different desktop environments so I installed Mate Desktop and Budgie Desktop through `taskel` following [this link](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-mate-desktop-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux).
I then decided to go back to the Gnome Desktop so I uninstalled Mate and Budgie with a list of commands, for example:

```
sudo dpkg --list | grep ubuntu-mate
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-mate*
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-mate*
sudo dpkg --list | grep libmate
sudo apt-get remove libmate*
sudo apt-get purge libmate*
```

Now I am experiencing several problems on booting.
I [recorded a video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NKR-Dpw4TRoedYo7qGM6T-BIzK5Sqm8B/view?usp=sharing) of the boot sequence where:

1. it shows a gray screen "mate-like"
2. it shows the ubuntu version in the left top area of the screen
3. it shows a very quick list of commands that suddently disappear
4. the login icon is different from the classic icon i saw before
5. **sometimes the login doesn't show and it stuck with the purple screen until a hard reset or pressing ctrl+alt-canc combination. I noticed that it happens only with power supply plugged in**

Maybe is something about the grub configuration but I don't know how to solve it.
Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gray screen seems to be GRUB2 theme for Ubuntu MATE. Remove it with

```
sudo apt-get autopurge grub2-themes-ubuntu-mate
```

then reinstall whole Ubuntu desktop task by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop^
```

and reboot to check the changes.

Comment: Very good! the autopurge did not remove anything but reinstalling ubuntu-desktop worked!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: I only noticed that the login icon is still "grainy"... any idea how to restore the original @N0rbert ?

Comment: I'm not sure which icon do you mean. You can change login screen to GDM3 by `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` and then selecting gdm3 there.

Comment: Never mind, I solved changing the icon in my user profile. Thanks anyway!